Is my Ubuntu/Postfix backup Email server working properly? : "connect to mail.mydomain.com[483.31.59.1]:25: Connection refused" How to fix?
I have two email servers running Ubuntu 22.04, with postfix. My main email server is working flawlessly. However, there are times when the email server goes down for maintanence or updates. During that time, any emails to that main server will bounce, UNLESS, I build a postfix backup email server, which will receive the emails while the main server is offline, and then forward those emails back to the main server after it goes online again. This prevents emails from bouncing, or me missing emails while my main server is offline.
For Reference, I have built my MAIN email server by following this tutorial:
[https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/setup-basic-postfix-mail-sever-ubuntu][1]
and
I have built my Backup Email server following this tutorial:
[https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/how-to-set-up-a-backup-email-server-postfix-ubuntu#comment-1041115][2]
My Main Email server has two MX records and an A record to go with it: mail.mydomain.com, and mail2.mydomain.com
My Backup Email server has one MX record and an A record to go with it: mail3.mydomain.com
In the backup email tutorial, towards the bottom, the author says

Now you can send an email from your backup MX host to your email
address with the following command.
echo "hello" | sendmail you@your-domain.com After the message is sent,
you can find the following text in /var/log/mail.log file.
Verified TLS connection established If your backup MX host tries to
establish TLS connection but can not verify the primary email server’s
certificate, then the following message can be found.
Untrusted TLS connection established

However, when I run the command:
echo "hello" | sendmail admin@mydomain.com

from my backup mail server, I get the following "connection refused" messages in /var/log/mail.log
Jul 25 18:12:31 mail3 postfix/qmgr[1810]: 870035EE8D: from=<Danran@mail3.mydomain.com>, size=248, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 25 18:12:31 mail3 postfix/relay/smtp[52903]: connect to mail.mydomain.com[483.31.59.1]:25: Connection refused
Jul 25 18:12:31 mail3 postfix/relay/smtp[52903]: connect to mail2.mydomain.com[483.31.59.1]:25: Connection refused
Jul 25 18:12:32 mail3 postfix/relay/smtp[52903]: connect to mail3.mydomain.com[175.56.103.435]:25: Connection refused
Jul 25 18:12:32 mail3 postfix/relay/smtp[52903]: 870035EE8D: to=<admin@mydomain.com>, relay=none, delay=0.46, delays=0.01/0.03/0.42/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to mail3.mydomain.com[175.56.103.435]:25: Connection refused)

It seems like the backup mail server is not able to connect to the Primary/Main email server. However, If I unplug my Primary Mail server form the internet, then send an email to an address used by that primary server, wait a little to confirm my email doesn't bounce, then turn the primary email server back on, I end up properly receiving the email I sent to the Backup server, in my inbox on my primary/mail email server. So, although my backup server cant seem to connect to my main email server to send messages from the terminal, it seems that the backup solution I have is at least partially working.
My question is, what exactly does "Connection refused" mean on my backup email server? How can I get rid of this "Connection refused" error on my backup email server, so that I can send myself an email from the back up server, and lastly, can you tell me if my backup email server is actually working as it should even though I am getting a "Connection refused" message when sending a test email from the server?
Please help me fix this so my backup server can connect to my main server and properly deliver emails that would have otherwise bounced.
Thanks for any help!
[1]: https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/setup-basic-postfix-mail-sever-ubuntu
[2]: https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/how-to-set-up-a-backup-email-server-postfix-ubuntu#comment-1041115

The fact that messages don't bounce when you send them after you unplug your primary mail server is not a conclusive test to confirm that  your backup mail server is functioning and queuing you e-mail. You need to check the mail logs on the backup mail server to confirm that. Because many normal SMT servers don't immediately return messages to the sender when they can't be delivered immediately. Typically  messages will be queued at the sender when all MX records for the recipient return a connection confused or similar error.

In general questions/problems regarding the usability of or inaccuracies in HOWTO's and manuals should be addressed to their author and not posted on ServerFault. - Please read our  guide to writing good questions and edit your question to contain sufficient details/errors/configuration-settings about your setup to provide you with a good solution (see for example the instructions on https://serverfault.com/tags/postfix/info ) , rather than confusing the issue with potential issues  that guide and/or how accurately it was followed.

Although the protocols involved as straightforward, running an email service can get very complicated very quickly. Meanwhile email is designed to run asynchronously - it should not be a big deal if a MTA is offline for a brief period. You probably have more important things to worry about now than HA.

@symcbean Without knowing more about what the mail server is used for, failovers may be mission critical if the one of the services of the mail server is a bounces address for mass sending services, where not having a mail server available can annoyingly quickly result in blacklisting the sending servers.

While not an answer to your question, an alternative failover can relatively easily be implemented in OpenBSD using OpenSMTPD (smptd), with something like less than a 15 line configuration file.

@Paul If HA is a requirement, then relying on MX priority is not a good idea.
